# Artificial Intelligence beta has started

Tags: discussion

After previous [failures](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/no-artificial-intelligence-in-area-51/), the AI site has its probably last chance to join to SE network. This is very related to robotics, since robot is a container for AI, so I believe a lot of people here have been using AI.

We need your help, since the site is struggling to find its own distinct and unique scope.

Please join: [http://ai.stackexchange.com](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93481/artificial-intelligence/visit) (to access go [HERE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93481/artificial-intelligence) and click the Visit link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [Artificial Intelligence Area 51 Site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93481/artificial-intelligence), scroll down to where it lists the "Top Beta Users". Just above that is a link that says, "Visit the Site Now." This appears to be the only way to get to the site.